# edit - backbone.js beginner attempting to load data

Tags: backbone.js

Attempting to post a beginner question but not making it past the "quality standards" filter.
I read through the thread on the error message. Are beginner questions too basic? Understandable but it might be better to put that in the error message. I include my code and my English is correct outside of the code block. The question has not been addressed, or at least is not returned from various search patterns. Is there anyway to appeal the filter as multiple rewrites have not cleared the hurdle or solved my, admittedly beginner, problem? In a last ditch attempt to hack the filter I'm pasting my original question in bellow with a few English only edits. edit - this seems to have worked but leaving above paragraph in to not jinx it.

Trying to load data into backbone but the render function is not firing. 
Firebug shows the GET is arriving with the correct data string. 
I have attempted to assign "this" to a variable and fire as a function but still no luck.

```
(function($) {
var DObj = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        dstring: 'dstring again'
    },
});

var MObs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: DObj
    },
    model: DObj,
    url: 'scr/bbone.php'
});

var MView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new MObs();
        //this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this);
        //this.collection.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        alert("here : ");
    }
});
var newMob = new MView();

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten the code with mockjax to mock response from the server, here it is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.5.1/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>

<script>

var DObj = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var MObs = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: DObj,
    url: '/movies'
});

$.mockjax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/movies',
   contentType: 'text/json',
   status: 200,
   response:  function() { 
      this.responseText = JSON.stringify(new MObs([{ name: 'Lincoln' }, { name: 'Argo' }])); 
   }
});

var MView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        alert("here : ");
    }
});

(function($) {
   var newCol = new MObs();
       newMob = new MView({ collection: newCol });

   newCol.fetch({ 
      success: function () { console.log('Success'); },
      error: function() { console.log('Error'); }
   });

})(jQuery);
```

I think there are many issues with code, the issue you were specifically asking for has to do with the server response; you should see an alert with the above code. I recommend you read backbone.js documentation for others.